# Счетчик аналитики в Next js

Tags: javascript, next.js

Являюсь новичком в next.js
Кто поможет подсказать как вставлять данный счетчик или с чего начать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Благодарю за ответы

Comment: надо скопировать этот код и вставить на сайт. Либо на какой-то конкретной странице, либо в `_app.tsx`  чтобы было на всех, либо в `_document.tsx` - чтобы с сервера приходило

Comment: Я пробовал реализовать через хуки
Но переменные он как будто "не видит"

Comment: Пробовал как useEffect так и useMemo

Comment: а причем тут вообще `useEffect` и `useMemo` - если тебе дана разметка html?

Comment: а как тогда лучше сделать?

Comment: В первом комментарии расписано.

Comment: Мне кажется, что способ добавления аналогичный варианту отсюда:
https://quasi-art.ru/library/it/nextjs-yandex-metrika?ysclid=ljms0xvnrz859535333